# Javascript Form Handle not Working

Tags: javascript, validation, return, alert

It DOES NOT return false and is not showing the error. See jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paYAp/2/

My JavaScipt:

```
function validateForm() {
    var error = "";
    var x=document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var y=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    /*  
    Additional variable defined here, commented out for debugging
    */
    if ((x==null || x=="") || (y==null || y==""))
      {
      error += "-First and last name required. <br />";
      }
      /*
      There were additional statements here, commented out for debugging
     */
    if (error != ""){
      alert(error);
      //document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Error: " + error;
      return false;
    }
}
```

I've also attached `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to the form.

Can someone please take a look for me and tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: Your code works in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/dRU8Y/ Note that you don't need to test `x` and `y` for `null` because they are set to the `value` property that will never be `null`. (On the other hand if the fields in question are not found you'll get an error because `getElementById()` will return `null`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not actually be returning `false`, you may be returning `undefined` as you do not return `true` if validation passes.

This will trick you into thinking your validation is correct, when it isn't.

Adding `return true;` to the end of the function may prove that you are not returning false after all.

```
function validateForm() {
    var error = "";
    var x=document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var y=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    /*  
    Additional variable defined here, commented out for debugging
    */
    if ((x==null || x=="") || (y==null || y==""))
      {
      error += "-First and last name required. <br />";
      }
      /*
      There were additional statements here, commented out for debugging
     */
    if (error != ""){
      alert(error);
      //document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Error: " + error;
      return false;
    }

    alert("Actually, returning true!");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Sohnee but i tried exactly what you posted and I'm not getting the "Returned true" alert either. It must be returning false, but why no alert?

Comment: Here is a JS Fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/paYAp/1/ - the most likely issue you have is a JavaScript error, for example the `document.getElementById` is failing because the ids aren't correct (I'm guessing).

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the function returns `undefined` in the case where validation passed, _if_ the function is called with `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` as shown in the question: the default behaviour (i.e., the submit) will only be prevented if `false` is returned.

Comment: Ah yes, although `undefined` is falsey, I just tested and the form would still submit.

Comment: I'm feel like such an idiot. There were about 15 more variables and 10 more conditional statements. I considered that I may have mistyped an ID, that's why I commented so much of it out. This is only a small chunk of the whole thing. I know that at least those 2 were correct. Is there anything else it could possibly be?

Comment: Best thing would be to stick the whole thing into JSFiddle so I can take a look - fork this one and add the missing bits: http://jsfiddle.net/paYAp/1/

Comment: It's confimed, I am an idiot. It's actually not returning false at all. What I did was copy the current page and rename it as the step2.php which is the action. I was going to go back and edit it later once I get this page done. So I thought it was returnig false but it was just loading an identical page.

Comment: Okay - you are going to hate this, but you were missing a `}` on one of your `else` statements: http://jsfiddle.net/3psrm/

Comment: I swear I checked that like 5 times. Oh well, Thanks for pointing that out! @Sohnee

Comment: It works now, but this didn't explain why it wasn't working with all that stuff commented out. I swear JavaScipt has a mind of it's own.